# Enable IPv6 on middle/guard relay but IPv6 does not work properly

Tags: network-configuration, ipv6

I used the following command to ping the IPv6 addresses of Tor directory authorities from my server (as described here under 7. https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/post-install/):

```
ping6 -c2 2001:858:2:2:aabb:0:563b:1526 && ping6 -c2 2620:13:4000:6000::1000:118 && ping601:678:558:1000::244 && ping6 -c2 2607:8500:154::3 && ping6 -c2 2001:638:a000:4140::ffff:189 && echo OK.
```

Response:

```
PING 2001:858:2:2:aabb:0:563b:1526(2001:858:2:2:aabb:0:563b:1526) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:858:2:2:aabb:0:563b:1526: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=23.8 ms
64 bytes from 2001:858:2:2:aabb:0:563b:1526: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=23.3 ms

--- 2001:858:2:2:aabb:0:563b:1526 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.345/23.553/23.762/0.208 ms
PING 2620:13:4000:6000::1000:118(2620:13:4000:6000::1000:118) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2620:13:4000:6000::1000:118: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=159 ms
64 bytes from 2620:13:4000:6000::1000:118: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=159 ms

--- 2620:13:4000:6000::1000:118 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 159.242/159.257/159.273/0.015 ms
PING 2001:67c:289c::9(2001:67c:289c::9) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:67c:289c::9: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=28.4 ms
64 bytes from 2001:67c:289c::9: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=28.3 ms

--- 2001:67c:289c::9 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 28.316/28.341/28.366/0.025 ms
PING 2001:678:558:1000::244(2001:678:558:1000::244) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:678:558:1000::244: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=16.7 ms
64 bytes from 2001:678:558:1000::244: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=16.4 ms

--- 2001:678:558:1000::244 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.364/16.514/16.664/0.150 ms
PING 2607:8500:154::3(2607:8500:154::3) 56 data bytes
From 2001:590::451f:6e46 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable

--- 2607:8500:154::3 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1028ms
```

At the end of the output you should see "OK" but there seems to be a problem. Can someone explain to me how to troubleshoot this so I can enable IPv6 on my guard relay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It looks like you have an error when copy-pasting your command.)

You ran the following ping commands:

```
ping6 -c2 2001:858:2:2:aabb:0:563b:1526
ping6 -c2 2620:13:4000:6000::1000:118
ping6 -c2 2001:67c:289c::9
ping6 -c2 2001:678:558:1000::244
ping6 -c2 2607:8500:154::3
ping6 -c2 2001:638:a000:4140::ffff:189
```

It failed when trying to ping 2607:8500:154::3. This is no longer an IPv6 address for any [authority](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search/flag:Authority). You should remove this address from the list of pings, and raise an issue on [Tor's Gitlab](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/web/community/-/issues) to update the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

no error with copy and paste - you've got the correct one-liner command. Two ampersands are launching the next command **only** if a previous one has not failed - and your last ping seems to fail: 2 packets sent 0 received, so the next line - that echoes the "OK" string - is not executed